# Problem with the Address Template Magento 2.4

Tags: address

I am having problems with the address template, when I add a new client it adds fine, but when registering the addresses it does not do it correctly, it leaves all the instructions for this untranslated, example:
Default Billing Address
{{depend prefix}} {{var prefix}} {{/ depend}} {{depend middlename}} {{var middlename}} {{/ depend}} {{depend suffix}} {{var suffix}} {{ / depend}} {{depend firstname}} ...

I leave a screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I've solved this issue, maybe it could help someone else, I have to say that I had migrated from M-1.8.1 to M-2.4.0 so I dont know you, but when I did it I had problems with eav_attribute_set table and if you wanted to continous with the migration you had to change Default for Default_1, ..., Default_8 and after migrate all data, in this table you found new records into, well I ran this query in mySQL :

select * from eav_attribute_set as eas inner join eav_attribute_group as eag on eag.attribute_set_id=eas.attribute_set_id where eas.entity_type_id=2 and eas.attribute_set_name='Default';

I took the value of attribute_set_id and change the file vendor/module-customer/API/ AddressMetadataInterface.php there I changed
const ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID_ADDRESS = 2  for ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID_ADDRESS = the value of attribute_set_id that I got in the previous step (in my case was 13)

and that's it

I know is not a good practice change files in magento core, so you should do it in your child theme.

Maybe you should read this https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5873

Answer (score 0):

The above solution seems to work by changing the value find in SQL query ,but we need to override this core file.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution (without any PHP files modifications):

```sql
SELECT s.attribute_set_id
    INTO @id
    FROM eav_attribute_set AS s
    INNER JOIN eav_attribute_group AS g
    ON g.attribute_set_id = s.attribute_set_id AND 2 = s.entity_type_id AND 'Default' = s.attribute_set_name
;
DELETE FROM eav_attribute_set WHERE 2 = attribute_set_id;
ALTER TABLE eav_attribute_group DROP FOREIGN KEY EAV_ATTR_GROUP_ATTR_SET_ID_EAV_ATTR_SET_ATTR_SET_ID;
ALTER TABLE eav_attribute_group
    ADD CONSTRAINT EAV_ATTR_GROUP_ATTR_SET_ID_EAV_ATTR_SET_ATTR_SET_ID
        FOREIGN KEY (attribute_set_id) REFERENCES eav_attribute_set (attribute_set_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
;
UPDATE eav_attribute_set SET attribute_set_id = 2 WHERE @id = attribute_set_id;
UPDATE eav_entity_attribute SET attribute_set_id = 2 WHERE @id = attribute_set_id;
UPDATE eav_entity SET attribute_set_id = 2 WHERE @id = attribute_set_id;
```

Then flush the Magento's cache.